# Creating 2D liquid with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What's the easiest way of creating a 2D liquid surface in SpriteKit? I don't mind using any external libraries.

So far I've used LiquidFun by Google and LiquidKit - a folder I found on github.

This is the effect I want to create. Fluid that fills half the screen:
https://j.gifs.com/m8aQ5X.gif

Answer (score 3):

If you just want something like what's in the image you posted, you're probably best off just texturing a rectangle with a water-like animation.

If you really want to simulate liquid, that LiquidKit repo looks very promising, I'd just read the Usage section in their readme.

Otherwise you could look into:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations

or:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics

both of which will be significantly more mathematically intensive but overall is just depends what you want to achieve.

Comment: If I were to do the first option, would that be creating a set of images and then iterating through them really fast to make it seem like a wave?

Comment: Yeah, essentially. I'm not sure how exactly it would be implemented in SpriteKit, but I imagine you can texture it with multiple images (one every couple of frames) which will create the illusion of it being liquid. It would also probably make any collision detection simpler, since you would just be checking against a moving rectangle.

Comment: that seems kinda tedious doesn't it? 

I had an idea though: Is there any way I can adjust the "hardness" of a node? For example, I can create a rectangle, and constantly bounce objects off it. If the rectangle is really soft, it will morph inwards every time an object bounces off (making it seem like water).

Comment: Not completely sure, but it looks like Sprite kit has an animateWithTextures method under [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/)

Otherwise if you want to go with what you're describing you'll want to probably read up on mass spring approximations of deformable objects:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics#Spring.2Fmass_models